# Cleaner way to hide multitple object cache inside instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, es6-class

I'm currently learning JavaScript, I've been reading some books for the past few days but I'd like some help with the following.

Let's say we have a class named `Label`. Its constructor accepts a `data` object containing some translations. I want to 'hide' these translations inside a Label instance and expose the `text` property to the rest of the program.

One solution would be having a `_active` property referencing a translation from `_translations`, a getter method `active()` returning the translation referenced by `_active`, and a `setLang()` method to switch between translations. But that would force us to always call `active` on a label instance to get it's text, like `label.active.text`.

(I'm aware that the `_translations` object is not really hidden since it's not private. The `Label` class may not make much sense, it's quick example I came up with, but the `_translations` object may be a cache for translations we got via an API call.)

**There surely has to be a cleaner way of implementing something like this, possibly avoiding the `active` method call on the label. Any ideas?**

I could have a `get text(){ return this._active.text }`, but what if the translation object had many properties?

Thanks in advance!

```js
const data = {
    // these objects could possibly have more properties
    en: {text: 'Text in english.'},
    zh: {text: "Let's imagine this one is in chinese."}
};

class Label {
    constructor(data) {
        this._translations = {};
        for (let lang in data)
            this._translations[lang] = data[lang];
        this._active = this._translations.en;
    }

    get active() {
        return this._active;
    }

    // switch between translations
    // may be used to get translations from an API endpoint
    // if the translation exists, read from _translations cache
    // if not, fetch from server (not implemented)
    setLang(value) {
        return (this._translations[value] &&
            (this._active = this._translations[value])) !== undefined;
    }
}

let label = new Label(data);
console.log(label.active.text);

label.setLang('zh');
console.log(label.active.text);

// I'd like to simply call label.text to return the text
```

Comment: Why would a single `Label` have multiple texts? That `.text` getter is the way to go.

Comment: Hello @Bergi , thanks for commenting. The `Label` class is merely an example. Let's assume that each object inside `data` contains more than just the `text` property. Or even better, a number of properties dynamically created. How would you handle that?

Comment: With a `getTranslation("text")` method probably. You can also make a `Proxy` for delegating all property accesses to that method as syntactic sugar.

Comment: Proxies are awful. Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` or something.

Answer (score 0):

After @Bergi's suggestion to use a proxy, I came up with the following which does solve my problem. It comes with the performance cost of using a proxy, but it's good enough for what I need.

```js
const data = {
  en: {
    text: 'Text in english.',
    color: 'red'
  },
  zh: {
    text: "Let's imagine this one is in chinese.",
    color: 'red in chinese'
  }
};

class Label {
  constructor(data) {
    this._translations = {};
    for (let lang in data)
      this._translations[lang] = data[lang];
    this._active = this._translations.en;
    
    // the 'new' operator passes an emtpy {} to the constructor
    // the constructor returns that object  in the end 
    // the 'this' now is said object (a 'Label')
    
    // then we wrap that object with a prox
    // that proxy redirects all calls to the active label
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: function(target, name) {
        if (name in target['_active'])
          return target['_active'][name];
        return target[name];
      }
    });
  }

  get active() {
    return this._active;
  }

  hi() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  setLang(value) {
    return (this._translations[value] &&
      (this._active = this._translations[value])) !== undefined;
  }
}

window.label = new Label(data);
console.log(label);
console.log(label.text);
label.setLang('zh');
console.log(label.text);
```